# How to access attributes for a UI element in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, uislider, ibaction

For example, I have a UISlider that calls `- (IBAction)sliderMoved:(id)sender`, which performs some task once a new value has been "slid" to through the `Value Changed` event. But what if I want to do something based on whatever its initial value is?

Hard-coding something to match the default value in Interface Builder would be sloppy and hard to debug later if someone changes the nib file. So, how can I access the default value set for this UISlider in Interface Builder?

AND, more generally speaking, how does one access these attributes for any such UI element? Are there setter/getter methods already synthesized for these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Maunil said, Use [bindings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html) to connect the UISlider in InterfaceBuilder to a UISlider object in the code.  Once this is done, you can access all its methods & properties.

To set the initial value, use the setValue: property of the UISlider, something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    // where mySlider is declared as a UISlider object and bound to your XIB slider
    [mySlider setValue:some_default_value];
    ...
}
```

See the [UISlider Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the syntax. As for the IB connection, would that be from the file's owner to the UISlider and then selecting the UISlider IBOutlet I just declared?

Comment: Yes, just right-click on the slider and drag it to your file's owner, if that is where you have the slider declared.  Note that the object your trying to bind must be declared in the header file in order for it to show up in InterfaceBuilder.  As lengthy as the [Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/ConnectionsandBindings/ConnectionsandBindings.html) documentation may seem, it is worth checking out.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I tried and after a little type-casting, got it to work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the slider in the header file as IBOutlet, and then hook it up in IB. Then you will be able to access all its properties in code.

Comment: Ah, yes. Silly OldMcStopher. I had an IBOutlet created for the slider's "output", but no IBOutlet for the slider itself. Thanks.